# Scriptfile error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a script file that has to display the number of orders.
The trouble I'm having is how do I come up with something that will select the amount from the orders table.  I have tried a statement but i don't know what to put after `WHERE`. This is what I have so far.

```
  use Cis11101_Northwind


 declare @OrdersCount int
 set @OrdersCount =  (Select Count(*)From orders where  )
 print 'The number of orders is ' + Cast(@Orderscount as varchar)
```

Comment: Just `select count(*) from orders` is enough if you want to count all orders. If you would want to count orders based on some criteria (say orders not older than 3 days) then you would put that criteria after where.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to always set the `WHERE` clause

```
use Cis11101_Northwind
declare @OrdersCount int
set @OrdersCount =  (Select Count(*) From orders)
print 'The number of orders is ' + Cast(@Orderscount as varchar)
```

You only need to set the `WHERE` clause if you want to filter table.